# How to prefix console.log output in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want `console.log` output to be prefixed to help to visually distinguish it from other log statements.

I tried implementing function like:

```
export const log = (...args: unknown[]) => {
  console.log(
    ...args.map((arg) => {
      if (typeof arg === 'object') {
        return prefixLines(
          inspect(arg, { colors: true, depth: null }),
          '> ',
        );
      } else {
        return prefixLines(String(arg), '> ');
      }
    }),
  );
};
```

However, I am learning that there a lot of edge cases, e.g. the above code will break usage of the following pattern:

```
console.log('foo %s', 123)
```

Is there a way to therefore prefix the entire output of `console.log` rather than trying to prefix the individual parameter values?

or maybe I need to use something other than `console.log` that takes the same inputs and returns a string result?

Comment: _"something other than `console.log` that takes the same inputs and returns a string result"_ - you can use [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/util.html#util_util_format_format_args) first, `format('foo %s', 123)` -> `'foo 123'`.

Answer (score 1):

After posting this, I realized I can just use `format` util.

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilformatformat-args

Example:

```
import { format } from 'node:util';

export const log = (...args: unknown[]) => {
  console.log(prefixLines(format(...args), '| '));
};
```

or even:

```
import { formatWithOptions } from 'node:util';

export const log = (...args: unknown[]) => {
  console.log(prefixLines(formatWithOptions({ colors: true }, ...args), '| '));
};
```

The above will produce colored output.